# How to pass html formatted text from string to a ListViewAdapter

Tags: java, android

How can I pass HTML texts I stored using CData in the Value/String to listViewAdapter?

In the strings I have IDs like `htmltext1`, `htmltext2`, `htmltext3`, etc. How do I fix the code in order to read text data from `string`?

This is What I tried which didn't work:

```
intent.putExtra("contentTv", Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.htmltext1)));
```

`ListViewAdapter` class:

```
// Set the result into textview
holder.mTitleTv.setText(modellist.get(i).getTitle());
holder.mDescTv.setText(modellist.get(i).getDesc());

// Set the result in imageview
holder.mIconTv.setImageResource(modellist.get(i).getIcon());


// listview item clicks
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //code later
        if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("NEW | Flower ports 1")) {
            //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
            Intent intent =  new Intent(mContext, FlowerActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Natural Flowers");
            intent.putExtra("contentTv", Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.htmltext1)));
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }

        if (modellist.get(i).getTitle().equals("NEW | Flower ports 2")) {
        //start NewActivity with title for actionbar and text for textview
        Intent intent =  new Intent(mContext, Flowerctivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", "Artificial flowers");
        intent.putExtra("contentTv", "Information about the artificial flowers...");
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the value that is been passed to the intent using logs

Comment: What kind of problem do you face?

Comment: Please can you give me example using the listView

Comment: Who can tell me what to do?